# JQuery Hide Label in a Div by ID

Tags: jquery, label, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have some divs that dynamically add a "fund-id" attribute when created since there can be about 50 of them on my page.  I am trying to dynamically hide and show elements in that div based on the fund-id and label id's in the div
the HTML would be;

```
<div class="qtyDD" id="divqtyDD" style="display: none;" fund-id="1">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeQtyType('D');"><label id="qtyTypeD" class="lblqtyDD" value="D">Dollars</label></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeQtyType('Shrs');"><label id="qtyTypeShrs" class="lblqtyDD" value="Shrs">Shares</label></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeQtyType('Full');"><label id="qtyTypeFull" class="lblqtyDD" value="Full">Full</label></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeQtyType('Net');"><label id="qtyTypeNet" class="lblqtyDD" value="Net">Net Redemptions</label></a>
</div>
```

depending on a checkbox selection i want to either hide(); the last 3 elements or show them all.  something like;

```
var fundID = fundID (taken from the function call, this is working fine)
if(this.checked){
   $('#divqtyDD[fund-id="' + fundID + '"]').next('#qtyTypeShrs').hide();
}else{
   $('#divqtyDD[fund-id="' + fundID + '"]').next('#qtyTypeShrs').show();
}
```

the labels just don't hide when being referenced with the next functionality.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique on the page. Use classes instead, and see where that gets you.

Comment: You'll also need to use `.find()` instead of `.next()`. See the jquery documentation for what each function does.

Comment: hey Jason, that's a good point, i was actually messing around with class names before posting this, i hadn't edited/updated it.  i'll try using find() for the elements and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#divqtyDD").children("#qtyTypeD").hide();
```

or you can directly use

```
$("#qtyTypeD").hide();
```

as the id is unique.

Comment: As they are id's is this not somewhat redundant? `$("#qtyTypeD").hide();` does the same thing.

Comment: the only reason i wouldn't reference them directly and i am doing it through the parent div and fund-id is because i could have ten of the exact same divs with fund-id=1, fund-id=2, so i want to only reference the #qtyTypeD within the <div> with the appropriate fund-id

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divqtyDD").children().slice(1)[this.checked ? 'hide' : 'show']();
```